# mkdir in bash script: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’

Tags: bash, scripts, mkdir

I have the following code on my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# vars
BACKUP_DIR= /opt/odoo12/database_backup_test

# create a backup directory
mkdir -p -v "${BACKUP_DIR}"
```

When the script is executed, the following err shows up:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space in your variable assignment that makes it an empty variable, change it to:

```
BACKUP_DIR=/opt/odoo12/database_backup_test
```